# Cannot get mod_rewrite to work in docker container

Tags: php, docker, apache, mod-rewrite, docker-compose

I am moving a PHP site to docker, I am using docker-compose. I cannot get mod_rewrite to work in docker although it works fine on the server I am moving it from.

I want to hide file names and parameters in URL's, they are defined in the .htaccess file.

Example:
I want to transform http://mysite/index.php?p1=login to http://mysite/login

I have tried multiple articles here on Stackoverflow and other places.

Please find complete source below.

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
    www:
        container_name: www
        build: .
        restart: always
        ports: 
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./public_html/:/var/www/html
            - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/30-custom.ini
        links:
            - db
        networks:
            - default
    db:
      container_name: db
      image: mysql:5.7
      restart: always
      environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: a1234
          MYSQL_DATABASE: test
          MYSQL_USER: test
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: a1234
      ports:
          - "3306:3306"
      volumes:
          - ./dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
          - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
      networks:
          - default
    phpmyadmin:
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        links: 
            - db:db
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
volumes:
    persistent:
```

---

### Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

# Install stuff
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install sudo unzip wget -y
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

# Configure stuff
COPY ./n2.nothing.com.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/n2.nothing.com.conf
RUN ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/n2.nothing.com.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/n2.nothing.com.conf
#RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www
#RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod ssl
RUN service apache2 restart

EXPOSE 80
```

---

### n2.nothing.com.conf

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Allow From All
        RewriteEngine On
      
        RewriteRule ^signup\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=signup&p2=$1&p3=$2 [L]
        RewriteRule ^signup\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=signup&p2=$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^signup/?$ ./index.php?p1=signup [L,NC,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^verify\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=verify&p2=$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^login\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=login&p2=$1&p3=$2 [L]
        RewriteRule ^login\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=login&p2=$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^login/?$ ./index.php?p1=login [L,NC,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^logout/?$ ./app/logout/ [L,NC,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^cart/?$ ./index.php?p1=cart [L,NC,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^checkout/?$ ./index.php?p1=checkout [L,NC,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^payment/?$ ./index.php?p1=payment [L,NC,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^account\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=account&p2=$1&p3=$2 [L]
        RewriteRule ^account\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=account&p2=$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^account/?$ ./index.php?p1=account [L,NC,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^fapi\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=fapi&p2=$1&p3=$2&ui=0 [L]
        RewriteRule ^fapi\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=fapi&p2=$1&ui=0 [L]
        RewriteRule ^fapi/?$ ./index.php?p1=fapi&ui=0 [L,NC,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^admin/?$ ./index.php?p1=admin [L,NC,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^designer\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=designer&p2=$1&p3=$2 [L]
        RewriteRule ^designer\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=designer&p2=$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^designer/?$ ./index.php?p1=designer [L,NC,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^product\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=product&p2=$1&p3=$2 [L]
        RewriteRule ^product\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=product&p2=$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^product/?$ ./index.php?p1=product [L,NC,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^checkout/?$ ./index.php?p1=checkout [L,NC,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^contact\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=contact&p2=$1&p3=$2 [L]
        RewriteRule ^contact\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=contact&p2=$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^contact/?$ ./index.php?p1=contact [L,NC,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^cron/?$ ./index.php?p1=cron [L,NC,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^terms/?$ ./index.php?p1=terms [L,NC,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^privacy/?$ ./index.php?p1=privacy [L,NC,QSA]
    </Directory>

    ServerAdmin me@nothing.com
    ServerName nothing.com
    ServerAlias n2.nothing.com
    
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/access.log combined
  </VirtualHost>
  
ServerSignature Off
ServerName n2.nothing.com
```

---

### php.ini *(There is no content in the php.ini file)*

---

### Readme-txt

```
# 1 - First I build
sudo docker-compose build --no-cache

# 2 - Then I run docker-compose
sudo docker-compose up -d

# 3 - I log into the www container to look for errors in the /var/www/error.log file
docker exec -it www /bin/bash
# 1 - First I build
sudo docker-compose build --no-cache

# 2 - Then I run docker-compose
sudo docker-compose up -d

# 3 - I log into the www container to look for errors in the /var/www/error.log file
docker exec -it www /bin/bash
```

---

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^signup\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=signup&p2=$1&p3=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^signup\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=signup&p2=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^signup/?$ ./index.php?p1=signup [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^verify\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=verify&p2=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^login\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=login&p2=$1&p3=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^login\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=login&p2=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^login/?$ ./index.php?p1=login [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^logout/?$ ./app/logout/ [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cart/?$ ./index.php?p1=cart [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^checkout/?$ ./index.php?p1=checkout [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^payment/?$ ./index.php?p1=payment [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^account\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=account&p2=$1&p3=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^account\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=account&p2=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^account/?$ ./index.php?p1=account [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^fapi\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=fapi&p2=$1&p3=$2&ui=0 [L]
RewriteRule ^fapi\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=fapi&p2=$1&ui=0 [L]
RewriteRule ^fapi/?$ ./index.php?p1=fapi&ui=0 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ ./index.php?p1=admin [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^designer\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=designer&p2=$1&p3=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^designer\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=designer&p2=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^designer/?$ ./index.php?p1=designer [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^product\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=product&p2=$1&p3=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^product\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=product&p2=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product/?$ ./index.php?p1=product [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^checkout/?$ ./index.php?p1=checkout [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^contact\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=contact&p2=$1&p3=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact\/([^\/]+)\/?  ./index.php?p1=contact&p2=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ ./index.php?p1=contact [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cron/?$ ./index.php?p1=cron [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^terms/?$ ./index.php?p1=terms [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^privacy/?$ ./index.php?p1=privacy [L,NC,QSA]
```

---

### Source:
public_html/index.php

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $p1 = "";   if(isset($_GET['p1'])) { $p1 = $_GET['p1']; }
  $p2 = "";   if(isset($_GET['p2'])) { $p2 = $_GET['p2']; }
  $p3 = "";   if(isset($_GET['p3'])) { $p3 = $_GET['p3']; }
  $ui = 1;    if(isset($_GET['ui'])) { $ui = $_GET['ui']; }
  $mode = ""; if(isset($_GET['mode'])) { $mode = $_GET['mode']; }

  echo "p1: '" . $p1 . "'<br />\n";
  echo "p2: '" . $p2 . "'<br />\n";
  echo "p3: '" . $p3 . "'<br />\n";
  echo "ui: '" . $ui . "'<br />\n";
  echo "p4: '" . $mode . "'<br />\n";
  
  echo "<hr>\n";
  
  echo "<p><a href='./login'>test ./login</a></p> should load ./index.php?p1=login\n";
?>
```

---

Comment: Are you sure your .htaccess also ends up in the container? Can you post the .htaccess file here. It looks like this is the last file missing to make this problem-description testable.

Comment: Hi BertC.

Thank you for your response :-)


I have added the .htaccess file to this post.

I think that the .htaccess file is added to the container because when I add
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
</IfModule>
in the top and bottom of the file, then I get an Internal Server Error, but nothing is logged in the /var/www/error.log file. The same happens when I write some jibberige like 'fafasfasfas' in the file, it gives an Internal Server Error, which also indicates that the .htaccess file is in fact loaded.

Comment: It's almost like my configuration of the RewriteRule lines does just not match the URLs that I use to test it. And that's strange because. this exact example is working on the webhotel that I am moving the code away from

So there is some issue somewhere in the configuration, but I have not found out where yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for the issue.

Moving all content from the .htaccess, and then deleting the .htaccess file. And then moving the content into the n2.nothing.com.conf file.

The n2.nothing.com.conf file in the example has been updated.